# R: Compute multiple correlations by group (and save output to csv file)

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, mean, correlation

Is there a way to make a file with the correlation statistic between the raw number of fish observed ("num") and each environmental data column ("temp", "do", etc.) by species ("group")?

*As well as correlations between the means and medians of num vs. env. factors?

I'd also like to be able to choose which correlation method to use (Pearson correlation, Kendall rank correlation, Spearman correlation, etc.)

My data:

```
zeros <- structure(list(year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("2019", "2020"), class = "factor"), season = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("dry", "wet"), class = "factor"), 
    site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Hardhead silverside", "Sailfin molly"), class = "factor"), 
    num = c(0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 13, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 2, 
    0, 3, 0, 13, 0), temp = c(23L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 30L, 28L, 18L, 
    19L, 33L, 33L, 25L, 20L, 33L, 23L, 36L, 32L, 28L, 17L, 34L, 
    31L, 26L, 34L, 26L, 35L, 15L, 25L, 26L, 20L, 18L, 14L, 23L, 
    17L, 26L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 29L, 31L, 18L, 15L), sal = c(12.5, 
    25.5, 8.5, 15.5, 17.5, 27.5, 9.5, 31.5, 1.5, 34.5, 25.5, 
    21.5, 10.5, 8.5, 32.5, 19.5, 6.5, 5.5, 15.5, 28.5, 6.5, 3.5, 
    29.5, 13.5, 7.5, 16.5, 3.5, 28.5, 22.5, 5.5, 9.5, 12.5, 29.5, 
    24.5, 8.5, 32.5, 37.5, 3.5, 12.5, 19.5), do = c(9.66, 7.66, 
    1.66, 14.66, 15.66, 1.66, 14.66, 15.66, 0.66, 5.66, 10.66, 
    11.66, 4.66, 0.66, 13.66, 1.66, 13.66, 6.66, 6.66, 10.66, 
    9.66, 15.66, 9.66, 15.66, 4.66, 13.66, 1.66, 11.66, 6.66, 
    8.66, 12.66, 0.66, 6.66, 0.66, 9.66, 16.66, 1.66, 10.66, 
    15.66, 10.66), depth = c(120L, 161L, 52L, 52L, 43L, 105L, 
    165L, 23L, 79L, 136L, 41L, 59L, 65L, 118L, 122L, 69L, 137L, 
    88L, 152L, 105L, 108L, 79L, 96L, 80L, 22L, 110L, 157L, 118L, 
    126L, 93L, 156L, 64L, 74L, 24L, 111L, 113L, 157L, 78L, 121L, 
    130L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question is straightforward:

```
zeros.spl <- split(zeros, zeros$group)
zeros.cors <- sapply(zeros.spl, function(x) cor(x[, "num"], x[, 6:9]))
dimnames(zeros.cors)[[1]] <- colnames(zeros)[6:9]
zeros.cors
#       Hardhead silverside Sailfin molly
# temp           -0.3080334    0.36174046
# sal             0.1393580    0.47095129
# do              0.2544695   -0.06646818
# depth           0.1296208    0.08777425
t(zeros.cors)
#                           temp       sal          do      depth
# Hardhead silverside -0.3080334 0.1393580  0.25446948 0.12962078
# Sailfin molly        0.3617405 0.4709513 -0.06646818 0.08777425
```

Use `write.csv(zeros.cors, file="results.csv")` or `write.csv(t(zeros.cors), file="results.csv")` depending on what you want the rows/cols to be.

The second question is not clear. The means/medians of a group will be a single value so you cannot correlate it with the environmental variables. You could compute the means by group with aggregate:

```
aggregate(zeros[, 5:9], by=list(zeros$group), "mean")
#               Group.1  num  temp   sal   do  depth
# 1 Hardhead silverside 1.45 25.95 15.35 8.51 105.20
# 2       Sailfin molly 2.45 25.00 18.90 9.06  90.25
aggregate(zeros[, 5:9], by=list(zeros$group), "median")
#               Group.1 num temp  sal    do depth
# 1 Hardhead silverside   0   26 11.5  9.66 115.5
# 2       Sailfin molly   0   24 19.5 10.66  90.5
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Sorry for the confusion. I meant to add another column of "year_season". Then each year_season would have a mean or median by species to correlate with a mean or median temp or salinity.

Comment: In the original dataset, there are a few NA's. What's a good method for dealing with this? Omitting them prior to running the function?

Comment: Look at the `use=` argument in the `cor` function. You can remove all rows with missing data, `use="complete.obs"`, or remove observations with missing values on the pair of variables you are using `use="pairwise.complete.obs"`. In your case the pairwise complete option would be reasonable.

Comment: Cool. Thank you!